# What is INT=10H / AX=2000H in Windows XP NTLDR?

Tags: boot, bootloader, interrupts, ntldr

I currently disassembled NTLDR of Windows XP. During the process of booting, NTLDR uses the following interrupt:

```
INT 10H, AX=2000H, BX=0301H, CX=0H, DX=0H
```

I don't know the meaning of this interrupt. What does it mean?

Comment: Could you post a code/assembler output snippet with that interrupt?  It would be helpful to see that particular location in the assembler output.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the byte order (endianness) was computed correctly, and `AX` is `2000H` and not `0020H`?

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the answer is going to require a bit of assembly language to understand.

Of the multipurpose registers used by x86 and x64 processors, EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX can be divided into to halves. So EAX breaks down into AX and AH. The same holds true for EBX and so on. AX, BX, CX, and DX are the lower halves of the EAX, EBX, ECX, and EDX registers. The interrupt 10H is the video interrupt code.

Comment: *two...not to. gramer fale

Comment: I think it's unlikely to be using the extended registers for int 10H for backwards-compatibility reasons.

Comment: I actually want to know what does the INT=10h/AH=20H mean. There is no documented sub-service under the int10h/ah=20h, but it exists in Ntldr.

Comment: @JasonLane: You can edit that

Comment: @znatz are you sure the byte-order is correct?